# How do I sum the elements of an array list?

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist, while-loop

I'm trying to use a while loop to display the results of some calculations.

Each iteration through the loop divides two numbers, increments one number twice, stores the result in an array list, and is supposed to sum all the elements in the array list.

However, the result of my sum is incorrect and I can't seem to figure out why. I should be getting 1956.9272 but it displays 73.3576, any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Here's my code:

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class testtest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        
        // Initialize variables
         double num1 = 1;
         double num2 = 3;
         double sum = 0;
         
        //  A new array list is created
        ArrayList<Double> myCalc = new ArrayList<Double>(); 

         // While loop is started if num2 is lass than 99
         while (num2 <= 99) {
             
             //Divides 1 by num2
              double answer = num1 / num2;
             
             // Adds the result to the array list
              myCalc.add(answer);
             
             // Twice increments num2, which is the denominator
              ++num2;
              ++num2;
              
              // For loop iterates through each element in the array list
              for (Double result : myCalc) {
                  
                  // Sums all the elements in the array list
                  sum += result;
              }
                          
         }
         
         // Displays the results of adding the array list elements together
        System.out.printf("%.4f", sum);
        
            
    }
}
```

Comment: `//Divides num2 by 1
          double answer = num1 / num2;`  - are you sure?

Comment: Oops, no my comment was wrong. I meant "Divides 1 by num2".

Comment: Do you want to sum myCalc after all other calculations are complete?  If so, then move that loop `for (Double result ...` outside to just before `System.out.printf`.  However that doesn't quite give your expected results.  Your specifications need to be a little clearer.

Comment: Yes I would like to store all the separate results from each calculation in myCalc and then add them all together. Essentially doing the equation (1/3) + (1/5) + (1/7) + etc.

Comment: Why are you using a list? This could be done with just a loop. Is it actually that you are required to sum the elements of a list, but multiply each element of the list by some evolving factor?

Comment: Why are you using a list? This could be done with just a loop. Is it actually that you are required to sum the elements of a list, but multiply each element of the list by some evolving factor?

Comment: Good question. I'm using a list because I couldn't figure out how to just do it with a loop.  I tried something like this:                                                                  
                double num1 = 1;
  double num2 = 3;
  double num3 = 0;
  

  
   while (num2 <= 99) {
    
   
      double answer = num1 / num2 + num3;
    
   num3 = answer;   
    
    
     ++num2;
     ++num2;                                                                                                    But I could not get this to work so I started trying the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    double n1 = 1, n2 = 3, result, sum = 0;     
    ArrayList<Double> list = new ArrayList<>();
    
    while( n2 <= 99) {
        result = n1/n2;
        list.add(result);
        n2 += 2;
    }
    
    for(double temp: list)
        sum = sum + temp;
    
    System.out.println(sum); //1.9377748484749076
```

If you put the for loop inside while you get

```
double n1 = 1, n2 = 3, result, sum = 0;     
    ArrayList<Double> list = new ArrayList<>();
    
    while( n2 <= 99) {
        result = n1/n2;
        list.add(result);
        n2 += 2;
            
        for(double temp: list)
           sum = sum + temp;
    }
    System.out.println(sum); //73.35762984798366
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing `sum(k = 1 to 49) of 1/(1+2k) * (49+1-k)`. Or in java:

```
    double sum = 0;
    for (int k = 1; k < 50; ++k) {
        sum += (50.0 - k)/(1 + 2*k);
    }
```

This indeed is near to 73.

I can only guess that the original specifation also changed `num1` or more likely
`answer` must be added to every array element also.

Comment: No matter what I do I seem to be moving further and further from what my assignment asks. I'm just trying to do 1/3 + 1/5 + 1/7 + 1/9 + 1/11 + 1/13 + 1/15 + 1/17 + 
  1/19 + 1/21 + 1/23 + 1/25 + 1/27 + 1/29 + 1/31 + 1/33 + 1/35 + 1/37 + 
  1/39 + 1/41 + 1/43 + 1/45 + 1/47 + 1/49 + 1/51 + 1/53 + 1/55 + 1/57 + 
  1/59 + 1/61 + 1/63 + 1/65 + 1/67 + 1/69 + 1/71 + 1/73 + 1/75 + 1/77 + 
  1/79 + 1/81 + 1/83 + 1/85 + 1/87 + 1/89 + 1/91 + 1/93 + 1955 + 1/97 + 
  1/99,  but I must use a while loop and the denominator must increment twice. Any ideas or should I scrap this and start over?

Comment: Is not that the `sum for i=1 to 49 of 1.0 / (1 + 2*i)`? Smaller even. Say real answer is R, your answer = A, then it seems R = A²/2. One sees such square divby 2 in `for i in 0 .. n for j in i .. n`. A bit what you are doing with the array. **So, yes: start over with what the assignment is asking.**

Answer (score 0):

For debugging purposes, let's do the following:
Add `double ans = 0.0;` under // Initialize variables
Add `ans = ans + answer;` followed by `System.out.printf("%.4f %.4f %.4f =  %.4f\n", num1, num2, answer,  ans);` under `double answer = num1 / num2;`

This will show the running total and the incremental additions to the total.  I get

```
  1.0000 3.0000 0.3333 =  0.3333
  1.0000 5.0000 0.2000 =  0.5333
  1.0000 7.0000 0.1429 =  0.6762
  1.0000 9.0000 0.1111 =  0.7873
  ...
  1.0000 99.0000 0.0101 =  1.9378
```

So, perhaps the assignment has the wrong total, or there is something that you have not included.